# Build TensorFlow graph low-level

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, low-level

I've Graph which is an array of Links, where Link is:

```
class Link:
     from_node_id
     to_node_id
     weight
```

I want to build *tf.Graph* from this structure which will look like Neural Network. Every *Node* in *Graph*(tf.Operation) will do dot product between input link weights and output values from other nodes that go into that node and then pass calculated value forward.

I'm new to TF and not sure what is the best way to do that, so any help is welcome.

Edit:
A mix of pseudocode and Python code of what I need:

```
for link in links:

    if not exists link.to_node_id:
        create new "node_id" Node
    if not exists link.from_node_id:
        create new "node_from" Node

    add "node_from" to inputs of "node_to" 

    # weights for node
    # creates new variable or returns one already created
    w = [v for v in tf.global_variables() if v.name == "Weight_" + link.to_node_id + ":0"][0]
   add link.weight to weights
```

Comment: This sounds like it is just a multi-layer perceptron (MLP) with fixed weights, zero biases and linear activation functions. Have you looked up tutorials on how to setup an MLP?

Comment: Yes, that's kinda it. But I don't know how to build the whole structure.
How to in one for loop pass through links build MLP, setup weights and connect it with others.
I've updated the question with code example.